# GitHub Wrong User

Tags: git, authentication

I am set up a repo on GitHub and I am trying to push some files. I was using another account, but now I made a new account and configured it.

I generated a new keypair (making sure ssh is using it), and I changed the global git settings for github.user and github.token

When I do git config --list i get
github.user=newuser
github.token=12345678910111213141516

But when I try to push something I get the error:

```
ERROR: Permission to newuser/Repo.git denied to olduser.
```

Comment: Did you add the new keypair to your Github page?

Comment: yes, i added the new keypair to my newuser GitHub page

Comment: Those config entries have nothing to do with pushing to github.  You are sending an ssh key that the old user has listed as one of his.

Comment: I fixed it by deleting ~/.ssh/id_rsa* (even though I had generated a new one) and then running ssh-add -D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a host alias to work with a second account.

See details here: http://help.github.com/multiple-keys/